# Why I get "Not in scope" exception message?

Tags: haskell

I learn Haskell. My code:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  if length args < 2 then 
    putStrLn invalidCallingSignature 
  else
    dispatch fileName command commandArgs
    where (fileName : command : commandArgs) = args -- But I get an Exception: src3.hs:22:48: Not in scope: `args'
```

I am confused by exception I get for last code row. Why I get it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There `where` clause applies to the function as a whole, and the indentation is misleading you. What the compiler sees is:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    if length args < 2 then 
        putStrLn invalidCallingSignature 
    else
        dispatch fileName command commandArgs
  where (fileName : command : commandArgs) = args
```

So `args` is not visible. You want a do-notation `let`:

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    if length args < 2 then 
        putStrLn invalidCallingSignature 
    else do
        let (fileName : command : commandArgs) = args
        dispatch fileName command commandArgs
```

Comment: A case statement might be prettier here: `case args of { fileName:command:commandArgs -> dispatch fileName command commandArgs; _ -> putStrLn invalidCallingSignature }`, but it's really just a matter of personal preference.  The case statement would mean that a list traversal for finding the length would not be necessary, though.

Comment: Add a `do` after the `else`, or alternatively an `in` after `= args`.